# Sharing Session State across different zones in web applications

Tags: 2010, session, e-commerce

We have a SharePoint 2010 web application with kind of e-commerce functionality (for example, `http://sharepoint-shop`). User can save items in the basket which works through default Session State (`HttpContext.Current.Session`).

Anonymous users can do this too. They pick up the items same way, but before order-workflow is starting user must log in. After this browser redirects user to HTTPS zone (`https://sharepoint-shop`) and all session data disappeared (`HttpContext.Current.Session`).

Any ideas, How I can share this session data between multiple zones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple.

I tried to understand how works a mechanism for storing sessions in ASP.NET. In my case, the sessions stores in the SQL Server database `SessionStateService_bf7ce9929397425d9b58d03b91699180` (default provision). This database contains two tables `ASPStateTempApplications` and `ASPStateTempSessions`. If you look at this tables you can see the main idea why diffirent applications has diffirent sessions.
`SessionId` column consist of two parts: `%SESSION_ID%` (`HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID`) and second part is the app-hash. App hash is unique for each applications, actually it is hash-function of two variables: AppId and MachineName. AppId generated by `dbo.TempGetAppID` stored procedure, MachineKey is property of each web.config (or machine-level machine.config).

So all you need to fix the stored procedure and web.config. I added to the `dbo.TempGetAppID` procedure this line at start:

```
SET @appName = 'singlesession'
```

Then I provided same validation and decryption keys in the `<machineKey/>` config section of web.config for both zones - "http" and "https".

So I got single HttpContext.Current.Session for each web-applications.